# Defining a data type as MonadSample

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am trying to define a toy probabilistic programming language to test various inference algorithms and their effectiveness. I followed [this tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours) to create a Scheme like language with a basic structure. Now I want to use the [monad-bayes](https://github.com/tweag/monad-bayes) library to add the probabilistic backend. My end goal is to support sampling from and observing from distributions. This is the definition of my expressions

```
data LispVal = Atom String                  -- Stores a string naming the atom
             | List [LispVal]               -- List of expressions
             | DottedList [LispVal] LispVal -- List of elements but last
             | Integer Integer               -- Int
             | Float Double
             | String String                -- Str
             | Bool Bool                    -- Bool
             | Port Handle
             | PrimitiveFunc ([LispVal] -> ThrowsError LispVal)
             | IOFunc ([LispVal] -> IOThrowsError LispVal)
             | Func { params :: [String], vararg :: Maybe String,
                      body :: [LispVal], closure :: Env }
```

Now, I want to add MonadSample and MonadInfer types to support the functions in the library. However, simply adding `| ModelSample MonadSample LispVal` does not work. I went over the source code of the library many times, but I dont seem to understand it well enough, there are quite some monad-transformations going on. This is how they define basic distributions in the library

```
class Monad m => MonadSample m where
  -- | Draw from a uniform distribution.
  random ::
    -- | \(\sim \mathcal{U}(0, 1)\)
    m Double

  -- | Draw from a uniform distribution.
  uniform ::
    -- | lower bound a
    Double ->
    -- | upper bound b
    Double ->
    -- | \(\sim \mathcal{U}(a, b)\).
    m Double
  uniform a b = draw (uniformDistr a b)

  -- | Draw from a normal distribution.
  normal ::
    -- | mean μ
    Double ->
    -- | standard deviation σ
    Double ->
    -- | \(\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)\)
    m Double
  normal m s = draw (normalDistr m s)

  -- | Draw from a gamma distribution.
  gamma ::
    -- | shape k
    Double ->
    -- | scale θ
    Double ->
    -- | \(\sim \Gamma(k, \theta)\)
    m Double
  gamma shape scale = draw (gammaDistr shape scale)

  -- | Draw from a beta distribution.
  beta ::
    -- | shape α
    Double ->
    -- | shape β
    Double ->
    -- | \(\sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)\)
    m Double
  beta a b = draw (betaDistr a b)

  -- | Draw from a Bernoulli distribution.
  bernoulli ::
    -- | probability p
    Double ->
    -- | \(\sim \mathrm{B}(1, p)\)
    m Bool
  bernoulli p = fmap (< p) random

  -- | Draw from a categorical distribution.
  categorical ::
    Vector v Double =>
    -- | event probabilities
    v Double ->
    -- | outcome category
    m Int
  categorical ps = fromPMF (ps !)

  -- | Draw from a categorical distribution in the log domain.
  logCategorical ::
    (Vector v (Log Double), Vector v Double) =>
    -- | event probabilities
    v (Log Double) ->
    -- | outcome category
    m Int
  logCategorical = categorical . VG.map (exp . ln)

  -- | Draw from a discrete uniform distribution.
  uniformD ::
    -- | observable outcomes @xs@
    [a] ->
    -- | \(\sim \mathcal{U}\{\mathrm{xs}\}\)
    m a
  uniformD xs = do
    let n = Prelude.length xs
    i <- categorical $ V.replicate n (1 / fromIntegral n)
    return (xs !! i)

  -- | Draw from a geometric distribution.
  geometric ::
    -- | success rate p
    Double ->
    -- | \(\sim\) number of failed Bernoulli trials with success probability p before first success
    m Int
  geometric = discrete . geometric0

  -- | Draw from a Poisson distribution.
  poisson ::
    -- | parameter λ
    Double ->
    -- | \(\sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)\)
    m Int
  poisson = discrete . Poisson.poisson
```

Is there a way to make all of these be included in the LispVal data I have? Or am I just following a wrong logic here and is there a better way to do this?

I would also welcome any more suggestions to how to go about integrating this library in my language. And as a side note, my goal is not to integrate all the functionality, but just the bare minimum to make a functioning probabilistic programming language.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: To clarify, here is an example program that I want to be able to run with my language.

`(define (model1 upper lower) (sample (uniform upper lower)))`

This function will just return a sample from a uniform distribution with the given constraints.The haskell library allows to do this via following

`a = sampleIO $ (uniform upper lower)`

I want to be able to use the same functionalities. What I initially tried was just to put `| ModelSample MonadSample LispVal` which gives the error "Expected a type, but 'MonadSample LispVal' has type Constraint" I looked up the error but couldnt find a way to solidify this Monad into a type which can be used by my expression

Comment: I find this an interesting topic, but daresay your question is too open-ended as it stands.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Hello, what would you suggest to make this more clear? My main goal right now is to integrate the distribution Monads ``MonadSample`` in the data structure, but I can try providing more details

Comment: Well, maybe sketch out what you mean by “integrate...in the data structure” in pseudo-code, and in particular why you'd even want that and what about your simple attempt doesn't work.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I tried to add some more details with edit, is that more clear now?

Comment: How about `| ModelSampleFloat (MonadSample Double) LispVal` etc.?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Nope, gives the same error mentioned on the edit :/

Comment: No way, it has to be a different error at least.

Comment: @leftaroundabout it generates an extra error for the new LispVal, but keeps the previous error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data declaration needs to use concrete types, but `MonadSample` is a constraint. It describes behaviors instead of implementations. From hackage, one instance of MonadSample is `SamplerIO` which you can use in your data declaration. e.g.

```hs
data LispVal =
--  [...]
  | Sample (SamplerIO LispVal)
```

From a quick look at what you have though I would instead recommend 'compiling' calls to `sample` into your existing constructor for `IOFunc`. e.g. your example

```
(sample (uniform upper lower))
```

can compile into `IOFunc (\_ -> sampleIO $ uniform upper lower)`

This way you don't need to add every future monad that you decide to add as a constructor. They can all just run in IO.